# Combining println in Java

Tags: java

I'm using multiple `+` in the code. I want to know if there is any other way to do so without using `+` many times.

```java
package java;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("\n                  ------CALCULATOR------");
        System.out.println
        ("------------------------------------------------------------\n"
        +"                       1 - ADDITION\n"
        +"                       2 - SUBTRACTION\n"
        +"                       3 - MULTIPLICATON\n"
        +"                       4 - DIVISION\n"
        +"                       5 - MODULUS\n"
        +"                       6 - RATING\n"
        +"                       7 - EXIT\n"
        +"-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `System.out.println( . . . )`?

Comment: If your question is about Java, then please do not tag Kotlin. In any case, this depends on your Java version. What Java version are you using?

Comment: Replace each concatenation with its own call to `System.out.println`

Comment: I also don't want to write `System.out.println()` multiple times @fantaghirocco

Comment: the last comment should be part of your question

Comment: what makes you think the + has any impact on whether you are printing on multiple lines or not? all it does is make the code easier to read, it doesn't alter the output

Comment: If you're using Java 15 or higher, you can use text blocks, see the duplicate and [JEP 378: Text Blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378).

Comment: I only asked for various methods to do so. @user16320675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a method that you provide a list of what you want to print and it will format it that way.

It could look something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("1 - ADDITION");
data.add("2 - SUBTRACTION");

public void printMenu(List<String> data){
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    data.stream.forEach(d->{
        System.out.println(d);
    });
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
```

This would allow you to have more flexability and control, and you can call this using printMenu(data);

Depending on how much repetition you want to eliminate, you can do something like

```
ArrayList<String> data = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1 - ADDITION", "2 - SUBTRACTION"});
```

and create a print method

```
public void print(Object o){
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Which instead of using System.out.println you can then just call print. Which means you can do-

```
public void printMenu(List<String> data){
    print("-----------------------------------------------------");
    data.stream.forEach(d->{
        print(d);
    });
    print("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
```

TL:DR- depending on what you want and your requirements, you have tons of flexibility.